# Creating a variable on an ActiveRecord model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Somewhat simple quetion I think, but didn't really find an answer on google..

What I want is set the current_user for a model..
So I can do different validations per user..

Something like this:

```
var current_user # <= this is what i need

validates, :something, :presence => { :if => :current_user_is_admin? } 

def current_user_is_admin?
    current_user.user_type == 1
end
```

So in the controller I can set the current_user before saving the record..

Hope it makes sense..

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"var" doesn't really make sense, because of Ruby's slapdash style. attr_accessor may be what you want:

```
attr_accessor :current_user
```

that defines a reader and a writer method for current_user.